# Dojo iconItem: class name of a DOM button as icon

Tags: css, dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

Can anyone help me?

I'm trying to set the icon of an iconItem with a class name.

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/mobile/IconItem.html
Here you can see that you can set the parameter 'icon' as a class name.

"An icon to display at the left of the item. The value can be either a path for an image file or a class name of a DOM button. If icon is not specified, the iconBase parameter of the parent widget is used. Default icon size for List Items is 29px wide by 29px height."

When I set a class name, it looks for an image with that name.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. In the following link you can find al the class items you can use http://www.caleblloyd.com/software/dojo-dojox-mobile-mbldombutton-icon-list-android-iphone/…  If you type 'mblDomButton + name' you can use that as an icon. A trick to use your own css class is 'mblDomButton yourOwnClass', that will generate a div with a class instead of an image!